# Set Theory element argument proof help please

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Prove that $(A U B)$ = $A$ or $B$ - $A$ and $B$

Comment: It does look like a right approach, though you may need to clean up your wording a little bit. For example, your third sentence "Then S_1\subseteq A such that..." don't seem to make sense there. I think you mean "Let S_1\subseteq A..." Proper wording makes it easier to read and understand.

Comment: @BenjaminT
Okay, thanks for the feedback. Does it seem correct otherwise?

Comment: ........BUMP....

Comment: For a quick read-through, I would say yes. At least you've got the right idea there. Maybe a little clean-up like I said earlier, but as an answer to an exercise, what you wrote should be good enough imho.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the right idea, but your proof can be improved. To show two sets have the same cardinality, we just need to show there is a bijection between them.

In this case, define $f:P(S)\to X$ by $f(R)=R\cup \{x\}$, where $R$ is any subset of $S$. We need to show $f$ is one-to-one and onto. The sentence "every element of $X$ is the union of a subset of $S$ with $\{x\}$" means $f$ is onto. Indeed we can check for any $A\in X$, $A$ contains $\{x\}$ by definition. Then $A-\{x\}\in P(S)$ and is mapped to $A$ by $f$. Similarly, the sentence "if you take different subsets of $S$ you get different elements of $X$" means $f$ is one-to-one. Indeed, if $S_1,S_2$ are in $P(S)$ and $S_1\neq S_2$, their images under $f$ are $S_1\cup \{x\}$ and $S_2\cup \{x\}$, which are not equal. Therefore, $f$ is a bijection between $P(S)$ and $X$.